# change in base class requiring recompilation of derived

Tags: c++, implementation

in Bjarne's "C++..." I have just read that

> the way most C++ implementations work implies that a change in the size of a base class requires a recompilation of all derived classes

$12.4.3 p.318

in the size? or rather change in general?

Comment: If he says "a change in the size", why would he mean something else?

Comment: @H2CO3 That logic is incorrect. The question is not about what Bjarne meant, but about whether there are other situations in C++ when that applies.

Comment: @ap. I feel the question is about what Bjarne meant, indeed.

Comment: Fair enough, the way he has worded it. But I was looking at what he intends to ask rather than what he has written. To each, their own.

Comment: @H2CO3, no, the question is not about what author meant but how should I interpret this, and maybe, just maybe, if it shouldn't be "change in base class in general"

Comment: @ap. You have been proven correct, as OP's latest comment points it out...

Comment: @H2CO3 I find your comments as unconstructive

Comment: @cf16 Why? What's wrong with them?

Comment: The statement should be interpreted such that a change in size **requires** a recompilation _in most C++ implementations_ while changes that do not modify the size **may or may not** require recompilation.

Comment: @H2CO3 they are unconstructive

Comment: @Tim : your answer is in opposite to what Jerry Coffin replied

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain this properly. However, I do not see how this is in conflict to what Jerry Coffin replied. I absolutely agree with what he said, and I assumed that my comment did so, too.

Comment: Jerry said that any change will cause recompilation

Comment: No, he said that **a typical build system** will **usually** recompile if a header file changes, even if it is not technically **required** (such as a change in a comment line). Stroustrup was commenting on **requirements**, Jerry was commenting on **typical implementations** as of today.

Comment: no, you said: may or may not, he said: will, and this is what I thought, any change will require recompilation not only the change in size. thank you all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the typical case, a change in size requires re-compiling all derived classes. Other changes can require re-compiling derived classes as well (e.g., changing the order and/or type of members can require re-compilation, even if the size remains constant).

I think most of what Bjarne was trying to get at is that derivation is typically implemented as aggregation from the viewpoint of memory layout. For example, if you start with something like:

```
struct A { 
   int x;
   int y;
};

struct B : A { 
   int a;
   int b;
};

B b;
```

The memory layout of `b` will look like:

```
| X | Y | a | b |
```

...so when/if the size of `A` changes, the members of `B` will be stored at different offsets in the composite object.

With a typical build system, any change to the header that contains the base class definition will result in re-compiling all derived classes, regardless of whether the change would require recompilation or not though (i.e., if the header has a more recent change date than a source file that depends on it, the source file will be re-compiled, even if all that's changed is, say, a comment that makes no difference in the code at all).